# Select all one day back but not older as one day

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I try to use a Sequelize function to collect only table content that is older than today. But only for one day, not two days. As sample today
today: `2022/08/23`
values only for: `2022/08/22` but not for `2022/08/21` and older.

For this is use:

```
    checkDateBack: async function() {

      return await dayins.findAll({
        where: {
          added_at: {
            [Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal("DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"),
          }
        },
        raw: true,
      })

    },
```

I have deleted all entries for `2022/08/22` in my temporary debug table but the result is `2022/08/21`. In my idea of the function `2022/08/21` and older will get ignored.
So if I delete all entries for `2022/08/22` I expect an **empty** result.

Anything I did wrong with the function so it collects also 2 days old?

Comment: Please show the generated SQL

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need yesterday data, you need to get date range, use moment js for date

```
let date = new Date(); //suppose today is 2022/08/23 
let endDate = moment(date).startOf("day").toString(); // starting of the day 12 am of(2022/08/23 ) 
let startDate = moment(date).subtract(1, "days").startOf("day").toString(); // starting of the day 12 am of(2022/08/22 ) 

// use [Op.between] insate of [Op.gte]

return await dayins.findAll({
  where: {
    added_at: {
      [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate],
    }
  },
  raw: true,
})
// it will return all data of 2022/08/22
// for sequelize createdAt if dont have any custome date fild

createdAt: {
  [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate],
},
```

Comment: You shouldn't recommend using `momentjs` as it is [depreciated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status), see the guide linked for recommended alternatives for future use.